# UserVoice's OAuth Implementation in PHP

Tags: php, oauth, uservoice

I am able to get the Records of the [UserVoice](http://www.uservoice.com) by calling and Unauthorized Requests but now i want to create and Update things in which i need OAuth but i am unable to find the [UserVoice's](http://www.uservoice.com) PHP Implementation of OAuth and Create/Update/Delete with [UserVoice](http://www.uservoice.com) API is there anyone can guide me how to Implement such thing??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have quite recently worked on this and released an OAuth-based library which makes it a bit  easier to access UserVoice API from a PHP version 5 application.

An example on how to create a ticket using an access token for user@example.com:

```
<?php
    require_once('vendor/autoload.php'); // Using Composer

    $client = new \UserVoice\Client('subdomain-name', 'API KEY', 'API SECRET');
    $access_token = $client->login_as('user@example.com');

    $result = $access_token->post("/api/v1/tickets", array(
            'ticket' => array(
                'state' => 'open',
                'subject' => 'PHP SDK',
                'message' => "Would you have any OAuth example for PHP?"
            )
    ));
?>
```

Despite the fact that the library is still under development, I believe it's already useful to you. See the blog post and more examples like responding to tickets as an account owner at:

http://developer.uservoice.com/docs/api/php-sdk/